# How to get full urlPath from angular2 ComponentInstruction when using nested route definitions?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using angular2 with nested route definitions e.g. `/auth/login` is actually split hierarchically by path segment, with a parent component delegating routes matching `/auth/...` to an Auth component which in turn handles `/login`, `/reset` etc.

The problem I'm having is that when I intercept the routed `ComponentInstruction` in a custom `RouterOutlet`, the component instruction only contains it's own path segment.

Using the above example, the component instruction urlPath for `/auth/login` contains only `login` as it's urlPath value.  Really what I want is access to the full urlPath, or some means of reliably reconstructing this path?

Comment: The closest I found is `router._outlet._currentInstruction`, `router.parent._outlet._currentInstruction` but these properties are private.  Maybe creating a feature request to make them public?